# GCD for 2 gaussian integers is not unique

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb Z [i] =\{a+bi: a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$

We know that the gcd for 2 gaussian integers is not unique.

So if i found the gcd of $11+7i$ and $18-i$ in $\mathbb Z [i]$ how i can find the other gcd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GCD is unique up to units. This statement is true in every Integral Domain. So if you find a GCD for two numbers, then for finding others just multiply the GCD with all of the units of the domain (in this case $1,-1,i,-i$).